# Use input function and while loop to transfer a path in Python

Tags: python, input, while-loop, path

When I define a `filePath` and `os.walk`, it goes well:

```
filePath = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(filePath):
    print(subdir)
```

Output:

```
C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/
C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/a
C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/a\a1
C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/a\a2
C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/a\a3
```

But when I use `input` function and `while` loop, I can not transfer `filePath` to `os.walk(filePath)`, I don't know why. Someone could help me to figure it out? Thanks.

```
status = True
while status:
    filePath = input(r"Please write your path:")
    if filePath.strip() == "":
        status = False

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(filePath):
    print(subdir)
```

Output:

```
Please write your path:C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/
Please write your path:'C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/'
Please write your path:
```

**EDIT:**

```
status = True
while status:
    filePath = input(r"Please write your path:")
    if os.path.exists(filePath):
        status = False

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(filePath):
    print(subdir)
```

Output:

```
Please write your path:C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/

C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/
C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/a
C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/a\a1
C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/a\a2
C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/a\a3
```

Then it finish here, I want when the code rerun so I can write another path say: `C:/Users/User/Desktop/test1/` at one time, until the path I write is empty, it will stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `filePath.strip() == ""` use `os.path.exists()` to check whether the given path is valid or not.

**TRY:-**

```
import os

status = True
while status:
    filePath = input(r"Please write your path:")
    if os.path.exists(filePath):
        status = False

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(filePath):
    print(subdir)
```

**P.S.:-** Your naming scheme for `os.walk()` is incorrect, `os.walk()`, in general returns in a format **Dirname, SubDir_list, File_list** so you should name the variables in which these are unpacked in a proper manner. You have named the variable that will be storing the path to the directory as `subdir`, variable storing the sub_directory list as `dirs`, which could be quite confusing to others. So try naming them by the convention so that it is easier for others to understand

**EDIT:-**

```
import os

status = True
while status:
    filePath = input(r"Please write your path:")
    if os.path.exists(filePath):
        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(filePath):
            print(subdir)

    if filePath is "":
        status = False
```

This code will run until a empty string `''`  is provided as a filepath. (empty string means nothing)

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. One more question: some of pathes I get use `os.walk` have both slashes and backslashes, expamples: `C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/a\a1`, `C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/a\a3\a3_1`, how can I get the pathes using either slashes or backslashes, not mixed?

Comment: use `path.replace("/", "\\")` this will replace any forward slash in the path string by a backslash. Ex. `C:/Users/User/Desktop/test/a\a1` will become `C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\a\a1`. BTW don't forget to use the path string in raw format in order to prevent the unicode decode error.

Comment: Just find one more problem, the while loop doesn't iterate, when I type one path, I get `os.walk` results, it stops. I hope to iterate as more as paths as possible except empty one, the loop will finish.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand what you are trying to say, can you please explain it again, with some example code etc.